# Webcodecamjs demo not working for book ISBN number

Tags: qr-code, webcam, barcode-scanner

WebCodeCamJS:

https://github.com/andrastoth/WebCodeCamJS

There is no releases there, which one should I download? The latest is stable?

I downloaded the latest and extracted it under Apache, and access demo in my computer using HTTPS. The camera drop down: camera 1 (facing unknown). The camera name will be shown if using the online demo

```
https://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/webcodecamjs/
```

anything wrong? But the scanning QR Code is working anyway.

For scanning barcode, it is not working for book ISBN number. Not working for the barcode on the plastic water bottle.

Comment: not working for scanning product barcode. Take about several minutes to scan one barcode, the result is wrong too.

Answer (score -1):

A lot of people get confused about this. Just to clarify, when you are scanning an ISBN barcode, it is usual that no information will appear. The reason is because the only way to access the database of ISBNs is to have an expensive subscription to Bowker's books in print, which runs $1,000 per year. Bowker owns the ISBN database and they don't make the info public. So it's not like you're doing a Google Search. In fact, you can't do a Google Search for ISBN data for the same reason, ie. Bowker owns the ISBN database and they charge for access.